# Use html() and replaceWith() together

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I want to replace one div with another and while doing so I want to populate the second div with the value read from the first one

So I guessed I should use both together but it isnt working. 
here is the code I'm using :

```
$("#test1").replaceWith($("#register p").html(programType).show());
```

The register div is :

```
<div id="register" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="field row">
                <div class="fieldName span0">Program : </div>
                <p>{{programType}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So instead of getting : **Program : Value of programType** 
I only get : **Value of programType**

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the **p** tag inside register. That for you receive *Value of programType*

Comment: I get the same result even when I remove the reference to p

Comment: To get "Program" you have to refference the class "fieldName span0". "#register p" gives you "Value..."

Comment: I tried this : $("#test1").replaceWith($("#register fieldName").html(programType).show()); I tried with .fieldName , same result

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
$("#test1").replaceWith($("#register")).show().find("p").html(programType);
```

It is not really clear what you want to perform, because it is not clear what is `#test1` and what do you mean by "instead of getting : Program : Value of programType I only get : Value of programType".

Comment: #test1 is the div where I can select the Program Type and on the click of continue button, I want it to be replaced with #register div , where I can see the program name selected by the user

Comment: And it should look something like -  Program : Value of programType      but I can only see the Value of programType with the label missing

Comment: What about actually checking the examples and then vote and accept when you find out the second one works (afaict it should)?

Comment: I've actually tried both the examples, Sir ! None of them worked. The first one is not what I want and second one doesn't return anything

Comment: Yeah, I understand the first one is not what you asked for (I can edit it away)... the fact that second does not work is strange, though; but you should see where you problem was: you show replace with the whole #register (which the code does) and the fill only the sub-part "p" (which `find` does for you afterwards). It should definitely have shown at least the "Program : {{programType}}" even if not replaced the inner part. You be more exact on what you want: "I want #register to be copied into #test1 and its inner p be replaced with value of `programType`"... is it so?

Comment: Exactly ! Two things are happening with everything I've tried : Either nothing shows up or only the value of programType shows up

Comment: As you can see, the code I put there does exactly what you want. It tackles the main problem you had: you have to first replaceWith the whole paragraph, then find just the part and replace its content (btw I would suggest you don't use `html` but `text`, it's safer). If it does not work, go step by step: `$('#test1').show(); $('#test1').replaceWith($('#register')); $('#test1').find('p').text('hi there');` and you see where is the problem (maybe `replaceWith` is fine with the selector alone without `$`, or something).